# Page break issue in browsers print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is how my Html page looks in print view.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHtdW.png]

I need to put it on new page when it breaks in 2 and for that need to insert below `div` before these elements (something which I am doing for other predefined new pages).

```
<div style='page-break-before: always'>
```

But I am not able to do so as these contents are dynamic and I have no idea exactly which **HTML element** will fall at this place.

If I somehow manage to track **HTML element** at page break point, I will simply put page-break code just above it. This need to be done on html page with `jQuery` as print view doesn't support js.

I tried to do it like this but failed here as well. Looks like print view doesn't support `position: absolute`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").append("<div style='position: absolute;top: 760px;page-break-before: always'>");
});
```

Comment: Maybe you rather want `page-break-inside: avoid` ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As page-break-* doesn't work on google chrome, here is the solution which worked for me. I set `display: inline-block` for all the HTML Element which I don't want to get separated between two pages.

```
.msgbx,.svnotice, .imgdescbx img {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Try this article](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)

Make Sure You use

```
@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```